# Equal - depth binning- whether it is just grouping data into k groups

Tags: data-mining, binning

A small confusion on equal - depth or equal frequency binning

Equal depth binning says that - It divides the range into N intervals, each containing approximately same number of samples

Lets take a small portion of iris data

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

If I need to bin my 1st column, what will be the results?
Whether it is just grouping the data or it includes some calculation like equal width binning.

What happens if number of elements to be binned is an odd number. How will I bin equally?

Answer (score 3):

like @Anony-Mousse mentions, it is not always possible to *exactly* get the same number of samples in a bin, *approximately* is what is desired.

I will walk you through the case when `unique(N)/bins > 0`, where `N` represents the values in an array to be *binned*. Assume

`N = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     2, 3, 4, 5,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
bins = 4`

here, `length(N) = 20`  and `length(unique(N)) = 6`, making `unique(N)/bins = 1.5 > 0`. Which means every bin will have approximately `1.5` samples. So you will put `1` in *bin1*, carrying over the 0.5 residue to the next bin, making the number of elements in that bin to `1.5 + 0.5 = 2`, so `2` and `3` will be in *bin2*. Extrapolating this logic the final bins will have the following split. `[1], [2,3], [4], [5,6]` of course `1` repeats 6 times and `6` repeats 10 times. 
I would not like the *ties* to sit in separate bins, that is usually the point in having bins (grouping values close to one another).

For cases with `unique(N)/bins < 0`, the same logic can be applied. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you cannot make bins of exactly the same size.

For example, if your data is

```
1,1,1,2,99
```

and you want 4 bins, then the most intuitive result should be

```
[1,1,1], [2], [], [99]
```

Most tools will produce one of these answers:

```
[1,1,1], [], [2], [99]
[1,1], [1], [2], [99]
[1], [1], [1], [2,99]
```

None of them have exactly 1.25 elements in every bin. The two last solutions are closest, but also the least intuitive. That is why one only demands "*approximately* the same number". Sometimes, there is no good solution that exactly has this frequency.

Comment: Say I am having 4- bins. From the answer you mentioned ,the data falls like this "[1,1,1], [2], [], [99]", so how we are droping the elements into these bins? Any equations?

Comment: ok. If I am having 8 elements to be binned into 4 bins. Then I need to sort the data and drop the elements. is 'nt it? eg: 4,2,1,8,0,9,5,5 sort--> 0,1,2,4,5,5,8,9 ; so bins will be like [0,1] [2,4] [5,5] [8,9] .Am I right?

Comment: Quantile binning is one way, but it can still vary in how *ties* are handled. The solution [0,1,2][4,5,5][][8,9] is equally well, just using a different logic.